# Get the row of UITextField inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have two `UITextFields` inside a custom cell of a `UITableView`.
I need to edit and store values of the textFields.
When I click inside a `UITextField` I have to know the row it belongs to in order to save the value to the correct record of a local array.
How can I get the row index of the textField?
I tried :

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

     currentRow = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;


}
```

But the currentRow does not change when I click inside the UITextFieldRow.It changes only when I click (select) the entire row...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
//For ios 7

UITableViewCell *cell =(UITableViewCell *) textField.superview.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblView indexPathForCell:cell];


//For ios 6

UITableViewCell *cell =(UITableViewCell *) textField.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Comment: Why 3 times superview?

Comment: there has been a change in the hierarchy of tableviewCells
So adding an extra .superview

Comment: Could you point me to the doc where this change is explained? Regards

Comment: while this approach works it is bound to fail and just cause problems down the road when apple makes changes...

Answer (score 7):

The text field did not send touch event to the table view so indexPathForSelectedRow is not working. You can use:

```
CGPoint textFieldOrigin = [self.tableView convertPoint:textField.bounds.origin fromView:textField];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:textFieldOrigin];
```

Comment: This is robust solution i guess. The accepted answer has dependency of super-view hierarchy and in that OS specific so now it bad solution for me.

Answer (score 5):

In iOS 8 I found that the simulator and device had different number of superviews, so this is a little more generic and should work across all versions of iOS:

```
UIView *superview = textField.superview;
while (![superview isMemberOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) { // If you have a custom class change it here
    superview = superview.superview;
}

UITableViewCell *cell =(UITableViewCell *) superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.table indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Answer (score 0):

1>You can achieve it by programmatically creating textfields in your CellForRowAtIndexPath and setting text field's tag as indexpath.row.
then textFieldDidBeginEditing you can just fetch textField.tag and achieve what you want.

2>another way is to have 2 custom cells in one table view. in that way you cam place text feild individually and set their tags from your utility panel.

Comment: No, because I have 2s.

Comment: i understand that you have 2 textfields. but rather then taking text field directly into your cell. just create them programatically.

Comment: how many textfields you have is irrelevant to determining which row you are on , make all the textfields have the same tag as the row

Comment: He needs to identify textfields individually, thats why i suggested him to tag textfield after creating then in CellForRowAtIndexPath and identify TextFields in  textFieldDidBeginEditing using tags.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create a custom cell, and put whatever custom UI elements I need inside and create a property `indexPath` which gets set when the cell is dequeued. Then I pass the indexPath along to the custom elements in `didSet`.

```
class EditableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: TableViewTextField!

    var indexPath: IndexPath? {
       didSet {
           //pass it along to the custom textField
           textField.indexPath = indexPath
        }
    }
}


class TableViewTextField: UITextField {
     var indexPath: IndexPath?
}
```

In `TableView`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditableCell") as! EditableTableViewCell
        cell.indexPath = indexPath
        return cell
}
```

Then I implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, and since the textField has its indexPath you will always know where it came from.
Not sure where the best place to set the delegate is. The easiest is to set it when the cell is dequeued.

```
override func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    guard let myTextField = textField as? TableViewTextField else { fatalError() }
    guard let indexPath = myTextField.indexPath else { fatalError() }
 }
```